# jquery does not work in my WebView

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, webview

I am making an iOS application using a WebView from my webapp.
I am having a problem with a jquery button. I am using jQuery 2.1.4. Here is my code:

```
$("#fakeinput").click(function() {
    $("#fos_user_profile_form_profilePictureFile").click();
});
```

I am trying to create a button "fakeinput" that calls a form to upload a profile picture. This works well on my webapp, but it does not work on my application. Am I missing something? It used to work when I used this but I had to spam the button to make it work:

```
$(document).on('touchstart click', '#fakeinput', function(){
    $("#fos_user_profile_form_profilePictureFile").click();
});
```

Do you have an idea of where it could come from?

EDIT: Here is how my button is called.

```
<div class="btn" id="fakeinput">
    {{ 'Changer de photo'|trans }}
</div>
{{ form_widget(form.profilePictureFile, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
```

Comment: Is the web view URL works fine in computer ? Can you post full codes ? We don't even know which jQuery version you use.

Comment: Yes, the webview URL works fine on my computer. I am using jQuery 2.1.4. Which part of the code do you want me to post ?
Here is where my jQuerry button is called :

`<div class="btn" id="fakeinput"> {{ 'Changer de photo'|trans }} </div>
    {{ form_widget(form.profilePictureFile, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}`

PS : This is twig